# ¿Tiene importancia que en una clase se implementa primero un metodo de una interfaz?

Tags: java, uml

[image: UML]

> El implementar los métodos de interfaz debe ir primero y luego el
>   resto, puede ser que cuando por ejemplo implemento una interfaz primero para 
>   que funcione  y añadir el resto, luego sino lo implemento luego más después del resto dará error...?

Comment: Desde el punto de vista de funcionamiento no, desde el punto de vista de optimizacion no sabria decirlo.

Answer (score 1):

El orden de los métodos no tiene ningún impacto a nivel funcional. Aunque para tener el código ordenado y entendible es recomendable estructurarlo como comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Si te referís a una clase que implementa una o varias interfaces, si. Es necesario, antes que nada, implementar todos los métodos que definen las interfaces en la nueva clase con el fin de que la clase compile sin errores.
El espiritu de una Interface Java es asegurar que toda clase que la implemente cumplirá con el "contrato" que esta Interface ha definido de antemano. Este "contrato" no es mas que una serie de métodos que deben ser implementados (aunque el cuerpo del metodo este en blanco) en forma obligatoria.
En términos de performance el orden no afecta de ninguna forma ya que incluso el IDE cambia el orden de las variables y métodos a gusto del usuario, simplemente sera mas sencillo y animoso, en tiempo de codificación, trabajar en una clase sin errores de compilación.

Comment: "Es necesario, antes que nada, implementar todos los métodos que definen las interfaces en la nueva clase con el fin de que la clase compile sin errores". Esto no es obligatorio.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como declaro las clases es una clase muy pequeña

```
class marca extends fabricante{

   private $enteroId_Marca = 0;
   private $cadenaMarca = null;
   private $enteroId_Fabricante = 0;


   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   ///                                  SET´s                               ///
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   function setEnteroId_Marca($enteroId_Marca) {
       $this->enteroId_Marca = $enteroId_Marca;
   }

   function setCadenaMarca($cadenaMarca) {
       $this->cadenaMarca = $cadenaMarca;
   }

   function setEnteroId_Fabricante($enteroId_Fabricante) {
       $this->enteroId_Fabricante = $enteroId_Fabricante;
   }

   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   ///                                   GET´s                              ///
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   function getEnteroId_Marca() {
       return $this->enteroId_Marca;
   }

   function getCadenaMarca() {
       return $this->cadenaMarca;
   }

   function getEnteroId_Fabricante() {
       return $this->enteroId_Fabricante;
   }


}
```

Es preferible desde mi punto de vista y la experiencia que desde un principio hagas la disciplina de realizar tus clases basándote en el análisis de lo requerimientos para tu sistema o programa, hay quienes por ejemplo como mi actual coach que *prefiere no poner los constructores y destructores*, para el anterior coach *en todas las clases pone  los constructores y destructores*, cuestión de estilo no lo se, pero cada quien tiene sus ideas.

Es preferible que las clases las modifiques lo menos posible, es decir solo si es requerido a tener que estar agregando *atributos y/o componentes* según los vayas necesitando. Creo que si realizas un buen análisis de los requerimientos de tu sistema tendrás la pauta para saber todo lo que ocupas en el diseño de tus clases, y al final los cambios serán mínimos en caso de que tengas que llevarlos a cabo.